# When compiled inb and outb in inline assembly produce "Error: operand type mismatch"

Tags: gcc, x86, x86-64, inline-assembly, osdev

I'm trying to code the simplest of the kernels for 64 bits arch and I'm having trouble with keyboard input.

I'm currently implementing this two functions to manage I/O

```
unsigned char inportb (unsigned short _port)
{
    unsigned char rv;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("inb %1, %0" : "=a" (rv) : "dN" (_port));
    return rv;
}

void outportb (unsigned short _port, unsigned char _data)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %1, %0" : : "dN" (_port), "a" (_data));
}
```

But I'm getting this assembler error:

```
main.c: Mensajes del ensamblador:
main.c:51: Error: no coincide el tipo de operando para «in»
main.c:61: Error: no coincide el tipo de operando para «out»
```

Or in English:

```
main.c: Assembler messages:
main.c:51: Error: operand type mismatch for `in'
main.c:61: Error: operand type mismatch for `out'
```

My guess is that this code (that I got from http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/creatingmain.htm) is designed for 32 bits assembly.

Any help on how to solve my problem would be greatly appreciated.

I build and run everything with this script

```
#!/bin/bash

nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
nasm -f elf64 loader.asm -o loader.o

#cc -m64  -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -nostdlib -c main.c
cc -m64 -masm=intel -c main.c
ld  -Ttext 0x100000 -o kernel.elf loader.o main.o 
objcopy -R .note -R .comment -S -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin

dd if=/dev/zero of=image.bin bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc
dd if=kernel.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc bs=512 seek=1

rm ./boot.bin ./kernel.bin ./main.o ./loader.o ./kernel.elf

qemu-system-x86_64  image.bin
```

Comment: You should be able to get the English message with something like `LANG=C gcc arguments`

Comment: Indeed, it *does* compile properly on my x86-64 GCC

Comment: If this is x86-64 Are you compiling this with the GCC `-masm=intel` option? If you are you will have to swap `%0` and `%1` around in the inline assembly templates as the source and destination operands are reversed from the default AT&T syntax if you use that option.

Comment: @MichaelPetch im running qemu-system-x86_64

Comment: @MichaelPetch im editing original post adding the build script im using

Comment: @MichaelPetch swapping %0 and %1 solved it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MichaelPetch answer please ;)

Comment: @MichaelPetch well I couldn't, all others were actually using wrong sizes.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It might sound weird, but i don't know how to mark a comment as answer.

Comment: @MichaelPetch that's so kind. Thank you so much Michael!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default GCC uses AT&T assembly syntax when generating assembly code from *C* code. This can be overridden by using the `-masm=intel` *GCC* compile option. In the update to your question you have `-masm=intel` in your *GCC* command line:

```
cc -m64 -masm=intel -c main.c
```

The code you found was designed for AT&T syntax where the source operand of an instruction is first and the destination is second. `-masm=intel` option has reversed that behavior. You have two choices. Reverse the operands in the inline assembly so they are destination, source (intel syntax) like this:

```
unsigned char inportb (unsigned short _port)
{
    unsigned char rv;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("inb %0, %1" : "=a" (rv) : "dN" (_port));
    return rv;
}

void outportb (unsigned short _port, unsigned char _data)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %0, %1" : : "dN" (_port), "a" (_data));
}
```

The other option is to remove `-masm=intel` option from your GCC command line and keep the code as is. This might be preferable as a significant amount of OS Development code uses AT&T syntax for inline assembly.

---

Note: You might want to consider using `gcc` instead of just `cc`